# Ember - triggerEvent helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I'm having trouble triggering a "change" event in an ember acceptance test.

I have a rangeslider with an observed 'value' property. On change, the slider sends an api request which updates the url with params based on the slider value.

I am able to change the value of the slider in my test using jQuery, which successfully updates the slider in the UI...

`$("#slider").val(3.0).change();`

...but the change event isn't fired, so no api call. This same setup is working fine for similar tests where I am able to use "click" or "fillIn" to trigger a request.

I've tried using both the run loop and the triggerEvent helper (see below) but am having no luck.

```
    // 1. using the run loop -- updates UI, but no change event fired

    Ember.run(function() {
      $("#gpa-slider").val(3.0).change();
    });
    andThen(() => {
      assert.equal(currentURL(), "/athletes?gpa=3.0")
    });


    //2. using triggerEvent helper -- 
    //   doesn't update UI, slider value, or trigger change event

    triggerEvent('#gpa-slider', 'change', {value: 3.8} )

    andThen(() => {
      assert.equal(currentURL(), "/athletes?gpa=3.0")
    });
```

Am I setting up triggerEvent() incorrectly? Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the change event to fire by clicking on the slider handle.

```
click(Ember.$('.rangeslider__handle'));
andThen(() => {
  assert.equal(currentURL(), '/athletes?gpa=3.0');
});
```

I still don't know what I was doing wrong with the triggerEvent() helper, but maybe this will help some poor soul in the future.